# FullCalendar jQuery! Can I Select Only one timeslots by clicking?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, calendar, fullcalendar, timeslots

In the Calendar "FullCalendar" made by http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

I need the user can only select one timeslots by clicking in agendaWeek view mode!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more info you can provide, the more relevant answers we can provide. From what I understand, you can do this by combining dayclick with the select method. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_method/

Use dayclick to listen for a times lot selection and then use the select method to select the times slot given. I haven't tested this myself but  in theory it should work.

Comment: Hello my friend ! Thanx for your pront answer ! As soon i can test the solution you explain to me ! I post here its work or not ! but like you say "in theory it should work." ! Thanx my friend

Answer (score 0):

First define your minutes for slot

```
MINUTES_FOR_SLOT = 60;
```

then create your calendar using your minutes for slot, and validate the difference between start and end dates selected, if the difference in minutes is greater than `MINUTES_FOR_SLOT` then return false

```
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                defaultView  : 'agendaWeek',
                slotMinutes  : MINUTES_FOR_SLOT,
                select: function(start, end) {

                    var a = moment(start.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
                    var b = moment(end.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
                    var diffMinutes = b.diff(a, 'minutes')
                    if(diffMinutes > MINUTES_FOR_SLOT) {
                        alert("multiple slot selection is not available");
                        return false;            
                    }
                },
             });
```